# How to know the Ambassador service prefix at runtime in my microservice in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ambassador

Is there a way to learn the Ambassador service prefix at runtime in my microservice in Kubernetes?

Taking this config example:

```
---
apiVersion: ambassador/v1
kind: Mapping
name: myservice_get_mapping
prefix: /myprefix/
service: myservice
```

From within my docker container, I would like to get the '/myprefix/'. Either via some env variable to the deployment or programmatically if cannot be done using env variable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the fact that [Ambassador](https://www.getambassador.io) `Mapping` resource associates REST resources with Kubernetes services, you can fetch annotation metadata via [JSONPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/) and then parse `prefix:` field, if I understand your question correctly.

Example for k8s service from Ambassador [documentation](https://www.getambassador.io/reference/mappings/):

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: httpbin
  annotations:
    getambassador.io/config: |
      ---
      apiVersion: ambassador/v1
      kind:  Mapping
      name:  tour-ui_mapping
      prefix: /test/
      service: http://tour
spec:
  ports:
  - name: httpbin
    port: 80
```

Command line to fetch `prefix:` field value:

`$ kubectl get svc httpbin -o jsonpath='{.metadata.annotations}'| grep -w "prefix:"| awk '{print $2}'`

> /test/

**Update:**

Alternatively, you might also consider to retrieve the same result through the direct call to REST API through Bearer token authentication [method](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#bootstrap-tokens):

```
curl -k -XGET  -H "Authorization : Bearer $MY_TOKEN" 'https://<API-server_IP>/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/httpbin' -H "Accept: application/yaml"| grep -w "prefix:"| awk '{print $2}
```

`$MY_TOKEN` variable has to be supplied with appropriate token which is entitled to perform above query against REST API as I've already pointed out in my former [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52890977/kubernetes-api-server-serving-pod-logs/52894762#52894762).

Comment: That would require me to have kubectl within the microservice and also means a step to the shell. I assume that there is a way to do this via some programming language invoking an http GET REST call and that is what I am looking for.